# Test rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

I just deployed my RuleApp to the Business Rules service.
I can log in to the Rule Execution Server console and see it is correctly deployed.
How do I test the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Ruleset view of the Rule Execution Server console, I clicked on "Retrieve HTDS Description File", chose the options "REST", "Latest ruleset version" and "Decision trace information", and clicked on the "Test" button. This opened up a new browser tab which allowed me to choose the data format (XML or JSON) and then generated a sample payload (with tracing enabled since I chose the "Decision trace information" option earlier). I clicked on "Execute Request" and the server response was displayed.

However, then I discovered the new UI for the Business Rules service on the Bluemix console, which meant I did not need to use the Rule Execution Server console anymore to test my ruleset.

In the "Decision Services" tab of Business Rules service, I was able to see my newly deployed RuleApp and ruleset (I had to click "Refresh"). I clicked on the arrow beside the ruleset (the tooltip said "Test your service").
[image]

This displayed a "Decision Request" and a "Decision Response". I could choose the XML or JSON data format and the corresponding sample data was generated under "Decision Request".
[image: Testing the ruleset using the Decision Services tab of the Business Rules Service]

I then clicked on the "Run Test" button and the execution result was displayed under "Decision Response".